# How to pass data/Images from one page to another in Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wanted to send Data/images from one page to another. In the Homepage when I tap on the add Icon button image should be passed to the Cart page and if the icon is tapped again image is removed from the Cart page. But, the cart page should be accessed from bottom navigation bar.
but it is showing an error called **1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.**. when it calls the cart page.

HomePage.dart file

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: NavBar(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Dish> _dishes = List<Dish>();

  List<Dish> _cartList = List<Dish>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateDishes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0, top: 8.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_cart,
                    size: 36.0,
                  ),
                  if (_cartList.length > 0)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 8.0,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Text(
                          _cartList.length.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () {
                if (_cartList.isNotEmpty)
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Cart(_cartList),
                    ),
                  );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildGridView(),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _dishes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var item = _dishes[index];
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 8.0,
            vertical: 2.0,
          ),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(
                item.icon,
                color: item.color,
              ),
              title: Text(item.name),
              trailing: GestureDetector(
                child: (!_cartList.contains(item))
                    ? Icon(
                        Icons.add_circle,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      )
                    : Icon(
                        Icons.remove_circle,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (!_cartList.contains(item))
                      _cartList.add(item);
                    else
                      _cartList.remove(item);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  GridView _buildGridView() {
    return GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemCount: _dishes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _dishes[index];
          return Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.loose,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        item.icon,
                        color: (_cartList.contains(item))
                            ? Colors.grey
                            : item.color,
                        size: 100.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        item.name,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 8.0,
                      bottom: 8.0,
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: (!_cartList.contains(item))
                            ? Icon(
                                Icons.add_circle,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              )
                            : Icon(
                                Icons.remove_circle,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (!_cartList.contains(item))
                              _cartList.add(item);
                            else
                              _cartList.remove(item);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
        });
  }

  void _populateDishes() {
    var list = <Dish>[
      Dish(
        name: 'Chicken Zinger',
        icon: Icons.fastfood,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
      Dish(
        name: 'Chicken Zinger without chicken',
        icon: Icons.print,
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      Dish(
        name: 'Rice',
        icon: Icons.child_care,
        color: Colors.brown,
      ),
      Dish(
        name: 'Beef burger without beef',
        icon: Icons.whatshot,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      Dish(
        name: 'Laptop without OS',
        icon: Icons.laptop,
        color: Colors.purple,
      ),
      Dish(
        name: 'Mac wihout macOS',
        icon: Icons.laptop_mac,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
    ];

    setState(() {
      _dishes = list;
    });
  }
}
```

Cart.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;

  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);

  List<Dish> _cart;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  item.icon,
                  color: item.color,
                ),
                title: Text(item.name),
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _cart.remove(item);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NavBar.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sharewallpaper/cart.dart';
import 'package:sharewallpaper/main.dart';

class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavBarState createState() => _NavBarState();
}

class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    MyHomePage(),
    Cart(), ** This line is throwing an error ** 
  ];

  void onTappedBar(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTappedBar,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark), title: Text('BookMark')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it will throw an error because the constructor of the `Cart` class is expecting one parameter to be passed in. You could use a named constructor instead like this:

```
class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;

  Cart(this._cart);
```

That way, you can call it like so:

```
Cart(cart: _cartList),
```

But if you actually need the cart list, I would recommend that you write a provider to keep track of the cart data across screens.

Comment: Sorry! I did not understand and still struggling to clear the error. can you please explain it clearly. I couldn't call Cart(this._cart) using the above code.